# Implementing CircularQueue using Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, circular-list

I'm currently doing a project which will require me to implement a CircularQueue data structure in C++. Here is what I have so far:

```
template<typename Type> class CircularQueue {

template<typename Type> struct CQNode {
    Type head;
    CQNode* tail;

    CQNode() {
        this->head = NULL;
        this->tail = NULL;
    }

    CQNode(Type head, CQNode* tail = NULL) {
        this->head = head;
        this->tail = tail;
    }

};


private:

CQNode<Type>* front;
CQNode<Type>* rear;
CQNode<Type>** circularQueue = NULL;
int MAX = 0;
int currentSize = 0;


protected:

public:

/**********************************************************/
/********************** CONSTRUCTORS **********************/
/**********************************************************/

/**
 * @brief
 * 
 * [DETAILED DESCRIPTION]
 *
 * @param capacity integer size capacity of CircularQueue object to be instantiated
 */
CircularQueue(int capacity) {

    // Set the maximum queue capacity to the size passed to constructor
    this->MAX = capacity;

    // Locally set the limit (to be used as array of CQNode size) to MAX
    const int limit = this->MAX;

    // Create a pointer array of CQNode with size limit and assign to this->circularQueue
    this->circularQueue = new CQNode<Type>*[limit];

    // Loop over queue capacity, implementing CircularQueue type structure
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

        // set i'th element of circularQueue array to a new CQNode struct
        this->circularQueue[i] = new CQNode<Type>();

        // if the value of i is greater than 0, assign the tail of the (i-1)'th element 
        // of circularQueue to i'th element of circularQueue, thereby implementing the Queue
        // FIFO type data structure
        if (i > 0) {
            this->circularQueue[i - 1] = this->circularQueue[i];
        }

        // otherwise, if i is equal to the capacity - 1 (i.e. the last elementt of circularQueue array),
        // then set the tail of the last element of circularQueue to the first element of circularQueue,
        // thereby implementing the circular nature of this queue data structure
        else if (i == (limit - 1)) {
            this->circularQueue[i - 1]->tail = this->circularQueue[0];
        }

    }

    this->front = NULL;
    this->rear = NULL;
}

/**********************************************************/
/********************** DESTRUCTORS ***********************/
/**********************************************************/

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * [DETAILED DESCRIPTION]
 *
 */
~CircularQueue() {
    //TODO: Destroy Queue
}

/********************************************************/
/*********************** GETTERS ************************/
/********************************************************/

CQNode<Type>* peekFront() {
    return this->front;
}

CQNode<Type>* peekRear() {
    return this->rear;
}

Type peekHeadOfFront() {

    if (this->front != NULL)
        return this->front->head;

}

int getCurrentSize() {
    return this->currentSize;
}

bool isEmpty() {
    return this->rear == NULL;
}

/**********************************************/
/****************** TOSTRING ******************/
/**********************************************/

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * [DETAILED DESCRIPTION]
 *
 * @return string representation of this CircularQueue object
 */
string toString() {

    string temp = "[";

    CQNode<Type>* tempNode = this->front;

    int i = 0;

    while (tempNode != NULL && i < this->currentSize) {
        i++;
        //cout << temp << endl;
        if (tempNode->tail != NULL) {
            temp += std::to_string(tempNode->head) + ", ";
        }
        else {
            temp += std::to_string(tempNode->head);
        }
        tempNode = tempNode->tail;
    }

    temp += "]";

    return temp;

}

/********************************************************/
/******************* QUEUE OPERATIONS *******************/
/********************************************************/

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * [DETAILED DESCRIPTION]
 *
 * @param item Object to enqueue to this instance of CircularQueue
 * @return The item of data structure "Type" enqueued upon this CircularQueue instance
 */
Type enqueue(Type item) {

    // if the currentSize is greater than the maximum allowed capacity,
    // throw a CircularQueueException
    if (this->currentSize == this->MAX) {
        throw CircularQueueException("Circular queue is full, cannot enqueue any more objects!");
    }

    // if the front of this CQ object is null, assign first element of circularQueue array to 
    // front of queue and set the rear to the front (single-element queue)
    if (this->front == NULL) {
        //this->front = new CQNode<Type>(item);
        this->front = this->circularQueue[0];
        this->rear = this->front;
    }

    // else if the front is not-null, assign the tail of the rear of this CQ object
    // to a new CQNode with head = item, and shift the new rear to tail of old rear
    else {
        this->rear->tail = new CQNode<Type>(item);

        this->rear = this->rear->tail;

        if (this->currentSize == (this->MAX - 1))
            this->rear->tail = this->front;

    }

    this->currentSize++;

    return item;

}

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * [DETAILED DESCRIPTION]
 *
 * @return The item of data structure "Type" dequeued from this CircularQueue instance
 */
Type dequeue() {

    // Create a pointer to a CQNode initialised as NULL
    // this variavle will store the dequeued node
    CQNode<Type>* dequeuedNode = NULL;

    // if rear is empty, throw a CircularQueueException
    if (this->rear == NULL) {
        throw CircularQueueException("Circular queue is already empty, cannot dequeue any objects!");
    }

    else {

        // decrement currentSize of this CircularQueue instance by 1
        this->currentSize--;

        // assign front of this CircularQueue to dequeuedNode
        dequeuedNode = this->front;

        // set the new front of the queue to the tail of the current front
        this->front = this->front->tail;

    }

    return dequeuedNode->head;
}


};
```

Is this a good implementation for such a structure so far? Please mention any bad coding practices or potential problems that you can see with this code.

Note that my toString() function is designed as to only print a single "circle" of the queue, if there is a better way to make a toString() for a CircularQueue then please mention it.

Comment: *"Please mention any bad coding practices or potential problems that you can see with this code."* your question should be rather posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise that existed, I'll post it there then.

Comment: Don't forget to satisfy all of @Phrancis's conditions, and iron out *all* compiler warnings first.